# Bot cree que está tocando música pero no se escucha nada Discord.js Distube

Tags: javascript, nodejs, discord.js

Básicamente, se usa un comando para reproducir una canción en `Distube`. Reproduce durante 30 segundos aproximadamente, y luego, se detiene por completo. Aunque cuando reviso la cola, muestra que todavía está reproduciendo la música. No recibo ningún error en mi terminal, ni ningún registro relacionado.

No sé que hacer para solucionarlo, así que cualquier comentario sería de mucha ayuda en mi caso, muchas gracias.

- **index.js**

```js
const { SpotifyPlugin } = require("@distube/spotify");
const { SoundCloudPlugin } = require("@distube/soundcloud");
const { DisTube } = require("distube");

client.distube = new DisTube(client, {
  emitNewSongOnly: true,
  leaveOnFinish: false,
  leaveOnStop: true,
  leaveOnEmpty: true,
  savePreviousSongs: true,
  emitAddSongWhenCreatingQueue: false,
  searchSongs: 0,
  nsfw: false,
  emptyCooldown: 25,
  ytdlOptions: {
    highMaterMark: 1024 * 1024 * 64,
    quality: "highestaudio",
    format: "audioonly",
    liveBuffer: 60000,
    dlChunkSize: 1024 * 1024 * 4,
  },
  plugins: [
    new SpotifyPlugin({
      parallel: true,
      emitEventsAfterFetching: true,
    }),
    new SoundCloudPlugin()
  ],
});
```

- **play.js**

```js
const { EmbedBuilder } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  name: "play",
  alias: ['reproducir'],
  execute: async (client, message, args) => {

const string = args.join(' ')
    if (!string) return message.reply(` Especifica la cancion por favor.`)
    if(!message.member.voice.channel) return message.reply("Tienes que estar en un **canal de voz**.")
    client.distube.play(message.member.voice.channel, string, {
      member: message.member,
      textChannel: message.channel,
      message
    })
     message.reply(` **Buscando** \`${args.join(" ")}\`...`);

  }
}
```

- **addsong**

```js
client.distube.on("playSong", (queue, song) => {
  queue.textChannel.send({
    embeds: [new EmbedBuilder()
    .setTitle(`♫ Esta sonando: **${song.name}**`)
    .setDescription(`\`[0:00 / ${song.formattedDuration}]\``)
    .setThumbnail(song.thumbnail)
    .setColor("Red")
    .setURL(song.url)
    .setFooter({ text: `Añadida por: ${song.user.tag}`, iconURL: song.user.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true})})      
      ]
  })
})
client.distube.on("addSong", (queue, song) => {
  queue.textChannel.send({
    embeds: [new EmbedBuilder()
    .setTitle(`Añadido a la cola: **${song.name}**`)
    .setThumbnail(song.thumbnail)
    .setColor("Blue")
    .setURL(song.url)
    .setFooter({ text: `Añadida por: ${song.user.tag}`, iconURL: song.user.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true})})      
      ]
  })
})
client.distube.on("initQueue", (queue) => {
  queue.autoplay = false; 
});

client.distube.on("finish", (queue) => queue.textChannel.send({
  embeds: [new EmbedBuilder()
    .setTitle(`**Cola terminada**`)
    .setDescription("No hay mas canciones para reproducir.\nAñade una nueva o utiliza `$autoplay` para que nunca se acaben.")
    .setColor("Yellow")    
      ]
}
));
```

Según lo que investigué, `ytdl-core`, no funciona muy bien y lo debo reemplazar, pero antes de remplazarlo, quisiera saber si hay algún tipo de solución. Gracias por leer.

Comment: ¿Estás usando "ytdl-core" o "discord-ytdl-core"?, puedes probar a cambiar de una a otra.

Comment: Estoy usando ytdl-core y @distube/ytdl-core